# RandomForestClassifier giving 1.0 score for any parameters

Tags: random-forest

My model is giving 1.0 score when I apply best grid search results even after I change parameters (n_estimators from 300 to 100 and other such params). However I get .93 score when my parameter is not close to best grid search result.

It seems that once I fit my dataset to the best gridsearchCV params,I get 1.0 score and after that, no matter what I change in the parameters it returns me 1.0 score.

[image: Best GridDearchCV Result params]

[image: Changed params in Best GSCV model giving 1.0 again]

[image: Separately trained with other params giving appropriate result]

### Edit

I was playing with different parameters to find out which one might be causing this. Turns out, if `min_sample_leaf=1` my score is 1.0 no matter what other parameters are. setting `min_sample_leaf=2` got me a score of .97. Why might this be happening?

Comment: How many data records do you have?

Comment: 300. xtrain is (300,16) and ytrain is (300,)